# Heart Rate Monitoring on Android Smartphone using Camera

Tags: android

I'am new to Android development. I know that I need to learn a lot about this thesis topic that we proposed. Can somebody help me on how can i develop this kind of application? I need to know what algorithms should i use to make the application better. Thanks for your help guys. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that this will be a good place to start your search

https://code.google.com/p/android-heart-rate-monitor/